# Slow where in mysql.

Tags: mysql, database

I have little problem with mysql where in.

I have a table with 100k+ rows.
table has fields: userid, id

i need to get `id`  by userid.

userid ~ 30k

i used sql:

```
select * from table where userid in (....)
```

but when userid ~ 30k+ mysql is very slow.. more 10sec

i solve this problem with temporary table:

1) create temporary table _temp (id int, primary (`id`)
2) fill table with userid data (30k+)
3) do select:

```
select c.id from _temp t1 left join contacts c on t1.id=c.userid ...
```

in this case query runs faster. 
old query on test data 0.4s
new query on test data: 0.02s

is it good idea or maybe you know better way to optimize.

PS: userid is not table data. just int array

Comment: Show us the table and index definitions.  If you don't have any indexes, then that's your problem.  See http://use-the-index-luke.com for a tutorial on when and how to add indexes.

Comment: what about using group by or order by?

Comment: i have indexes on userid and id in `contacts`

Answer (score 0):

Some general hints:

First: check that the column `userid` is indexed. If it's not, add an index:

```
ALTER TABLE yourtable
    ADD INDEX idx_userid(userid);
```

Second: `IN` is meant to be used with small and deterministic sets. Consider this: for each row in the table, the `IN` condition has to be executed once. If the `IN` condition has a small number of values, that will be pretty fast, but if it's too big, you'll run into trouble. If you *really*  need to use 30k values, **don't** put them in an `IN` condition. Your approach is good: create a temporary table, store the values there, and join the tables.

*One last thing*: After creating the temp table, also index the column where you're storing the values you want to search; that will make your query run faster.

Answer (score -1):

you may like to use exists query

```
select * from table where exists (select userid from users where users.userid = table.userid)
```

Comment: where in this query i should put 30k+ userid's ?

Comment: @Antonf I think you already have a temp table in your question. use `exists` instead of `join`.

Comment: @Antonf in most cases, `join` is a method to link 2 tables. If you only need to check if a value is in another table, using `in` or `exists` is faster. If subquery is large, `exists` is faster than `in`